# Can I find when a page is last viewed in the Notion api?

Tags: notion-api

I am wondering if there is a possibility/workaround to find when a page is last viewed.

I have looked at the reference and have not been able to find it; only the `last edited date`. I have also looked at users, to see if they have some form of last viewed pages.

Within Notion itself that information is present. You can see who has viewed a page, when, and even whether they are viewing it at that moment.

In the end I want to run a script that checks all the pages on our Notion environment and flags the ones that have not been viewed for over a certain amount of time as ones that can possibly be deleted. The `last edited date` doesn't work here because some pages contain static info and may be viewed but not edited.